# Can a system have more than one dominant pole?

Tags: control, control-system

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_s1Z33VXjbU&ab_channel=NesoAcademy

I was watching the above video regarding the dominant pole concept.  It gave the example of a 2nd order system, where there will be one dominant pole, closer to the imaginary axis.

What will happen in the case of a higher (3rd or greater) order system?

For example, in a 3rd order system, how many dominant poles will there be?  One or more?

Comment: A second-order system has one pole pair. We can call it dominant or not - but the question arises: Dominant in comparison to what? There is no other pole that could be less dominant.

Comment: In any one year, how many winners of the football world cup can there be? In other words, if winning the world cup demonstrates dominance over all the other teams then, is it actually possible to have two football teams that win the world cup in the same year?

Answer (score 1):

It's relative to the location of the pole(s) you have closer to the origin.

In the video you link, for example, he states that the non-dominant pole must be >4x than the dominant pole for it to be considered non-dominant. I have never heard of such a rule, it actually sounds more like a rule-of-thumb, but it gives you the idea that non-dominant poles must be way larger than dominant ones for them to be considered as such.

In feedback amplifier design (and probably other fields that use classical control theory), a *non-dominant pole* is also considered to be the pole where the loop gain is less than 1 (i.e. below 0dB), in addition to being much larger than the dominant ones. This is because it provides an extra phase shift which could potentially make the amplifier have positive feedback instead. However, since the loop gain is less than 1, the feedback amplifier doesn't have the strength to suppress such high frequency signal anymore.

Comment: I think the last sentence in the 3rd paragraph needs rewording..It sounds like the opposite of what you want to say (I guess).